# When I "craft" a worker, do I lose the ones used for crafting?

Tags: motor-world-car-factory

In Motor World, you "craft" workers and "breed" cars. Go figure.

When I breed two cars, i get a new car to make. The others are still there to make. Guess its blueprints, but I am not so sure anymore. There's kissing of front bumpers and hearts.

But then there's worker "crafting". It requires you to have hired or "obtained" both workers of the recipe, and gives you another worker.

Do I lose the ones listed in the "crafting recipe", or do I just get a new worker?

The wiki is vague in this matter.

Comment: @Riftcaster Please don't make comments like that, they're really not appropriate on the SE network.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do lose the worker, it's like "combining" workers to make another one, otherwise you'd be able to make infinite workers if you didn't lose them. when you breed cars you get the ability to build a mutant car but keep the "blueprints" of the cars used to breed.